# Almacenar salida de comando nc -ul <puerto> &

Tags: linux, bash, script, netcat

Estoy trabajando en un script que registra datagramas UDP que circulan por una red de forma cíclica (el ciclo mas corto es cada 6 segundos)

Estoy tratando de registrar estos datagramas utilizando el comando
`nc -ul <puerto> &`

El caso es que al introducir el "&" para que el script continúe y no se quede atascado en el nc, por alguna razón la salida del comando no se puede guardar en ningún sitio.

He probado con `nc -ul 12345 & > archivo`, `var=$(nc -ul 12345 &)` y con `nc -ul 12345 & -o archivo`

Por el contrario, si elimino el "&" si que puedo ver la salida, pero el script se queda en esa linea de comando para siempre.

Como dato extra si ejecuto `nc -ul 12345 & > archivo` directamente en la terminal, funciona perfectamente, lo cual me confunde aun mas.

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres que se guarde en el archivo lo que tienes que hacer es decirle la salida antes de mandarlo a segundo plano.:

```
#!/bin/bash

nc -ul 12345 > out1 &
nc -ul 12346 > out2 &
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: `nohup nc -ul 12345 > out1` para que el proceso no quede atado a la terminal y puedas salir.